# Mobile Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

We have one website which is built using jQuery and JSON and I want to make my site work in Mobile too. Could you suggest any best mobile framework that can be easily integrated with my existing technology without much coding changes.

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) is really interesting.

You just need to re-design the layout and the code a little part of the output

Comment: Yes thanks for the response but its still in Alpha stage so cant proceed with that, any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

Excellent framework / boilerplate for simultaneous web app / mobile web app development:

**Skeleton:**
http://www.getskeleton.com/

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com). It supports a variety of mobile devices and tablets. It is currently in Beta 3 and very close to version 1.0 release.  It has come a long way since the "alpha" stage, as you mentioned in your response.  It has "Grade-A" support for a variety of mobile devices, including iOS 5.0 beta, and Android 2.1-2.3. Peruse the [Browser Support Matrix](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) for details.  The "depth" of this framework is impressive.  You will have to make a few "cosmetic" changes to your site and tweak the CSS "look and feel", but the framework handles the lion's share of the mobile device coding for you.  It also supports theming, as well as a host of great features!  I also recommend you view the documentation, at the link above,on your mobile device for a first hand look.  JQuery Mobile rocks!

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need to do a lot of coding changes depends largely on whether you did proper separation of concerns when developing your webesite, not so much on the framework that you are going to use for the mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

http://jqtouch.com/ is also worth looking for.
But it is limited to webkit enabled browsers only.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com) is the right choice for you I think. It has similarity with jQuery and it has nice predefined user interface and animation.
For second choice I`d Suggest you to use [Sencha Touch](http://sencha.com) It very nice..:D

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/). It is markup based mobile framework. You can transform existing website to mobile website easily.